# Where is this Definition of a Manifold from?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $M\subset \mathbb{R}^N$. We say that $M$ is a smooth submanifold of codimension $d$ or dimension $N-d=n$, if for every $p\in M$ there is a neighbourhood $U$ of $p$ and smooth functions $f_1,...,f_d$ on $U$ which have the properties:

1. $\mathrm{d}f_1,\mathrm{d}f_2,...,\mathrm{d}f_d$ are linearly independent in $T^*\mathbb{R}^N$
2. $U\cap M = \{f_1=...=f_d=0\} $

I have never seen this definition of a manifold and would like to know if there are any books working with it. I think this definition is closely related to the regular value theorem which is, again dependend on the exact definition of a manifold, a follow up theorem.

Comment: Probably all introductions to differential geometry prove, or leave it as an exercise, that that is an equivalent definition of an embedded manifold, using the implicit function theorem, or the inverse function theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember well, there is a similar definition in [Berger /Gostiaux book Differential Geometry: manifolds, curves and surfaces.](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387966267).

I have (unfortunately not at hand) a paper copy of the original French book.

The idea is similar to the way to define a linear subspace using linear forms.

Comment: You are right, Definition 2.1.1 is like that in that book. See [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/MvCBPn4).